# Python HTTP server keep connection alive

Tags: python-3.x, http, http-headers, httpserver

I am trying to test a HTTP client that is written in C, that sends an HTTP POST request to a local sever on my computer. I have added the headers `keep-alive` in my POST request that looks like this on the python3 HTTP server running on my computer:

```
<ip-address-1> - - [29/Apr/2018 18:27:49] "POST /html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Host: <ip-address-2>
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 168
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100


INFO:root:POST request,
Body:
{
"field": "abc",
"time": "2018-04-29T01:27:50.322000Z" 
}
```

The HTTP server POST handler looks like this:

```
class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.send_header("Connection", "keep-alive")
        self.send_header("keep-alive", "timeout=5, max=30")
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself
        print(self.headers)
        logging.info("POST request,\nBody:\n%s\n", post_data.decode('utf-8'))

        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("POST request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=8080):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    logging.info('Starting httpd...\n')
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    logging.info('Stopping httpd...\n')
```

The header response I see on the client side is:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.5.2
Date: Tue, 29 April 2018 16:07:42 GMT
Content-type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
keep-alive: timeout=5, max=30
```

I still do end up getting a disconnection callback, so my question is how can I set keep-alive connection parameters from the server side?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` emits HTTP/1.0 responses, as you can see in `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`. `HTTP/1.1` is required for keep alive responses, as seen in [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html) (or [for v3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)):

> **protocol_version**
>
> This specifies the HTTP protocol version used in responses. If set to 'HTTP/1.1', the server will permit HTTP persistent connections;
>   however, your server must then include an accurate Content-Length
>   header (using send_header()) in all of its responses to clients. For
>   backwards compatibility, the setting defaults to 'HTTP/1.0'.

Then as you can see in the quote, you'll have to set the right Content-Length for your response also.

Note that currently you send responses without body, you should use a 204 (no content) code for that and add the `Content-length: 0` header, or add a small body (with the right bytes count in Content-Length, warning, that's not a character counter, that's a byte counter, almost the same in ascii7 but not with other encodings).

Comment: Keep alive seems to work with the default `HTTP/1.0`, at least for [answering GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120102/python-http-server-keep-connection-alive). I also came across [setting it on TCP sockets themselves](https://blog.panagiks.com/2019/05/python-tcp-keepalive-on-http-request.html).